# Whats the latest Latest version of WSDL file?

Tags: soap, wsdl, docusignapi

Just trying to use the demo code for Java (DocuSignSample) - it refers to this wsdl:

https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?WSDL

Was wondering if this is the correct upto date WSDL for the demo since the readme file referring to the wsdl was updated 8 months ago from Git. Also build.xml does not have invocation even though the readme file mentions something about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is the latest WSDL.  The documentation is up to date, which means the wsdls referenced on [this page of the online SOAP API Guide](http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Introduction+Changes/Using%20DocuSign%20WSDLs.htm) are the latest.

```
Service API - https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/schema/dsapi.wsdl
Account Management Service API - https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/schema/dsapi-accountmanagement.wsdl
```